# Working with Sandcastle and Compact Framework projects

Tags: compact-framework, sandcastle

I have a set of .Net Compact Framework, 3.5, projects I have included into a Sandcastle project.
In VS 2008 the compilation fails with this log (PATH is the path to the solution):

```
Step 1 of 12: Change Directory

Changing current directory from "PATH\Documentation\Help\" to "PATH\Documentation\buildhelp"

Step 1 Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0156256

Step 2 of 12: Execute MRefBuilder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Sandcastle\ProductionTools\MRefBuilder /config:"PATH\Documentation\Help\Presentation\Style\Configuration\MRefBuilder.config" /out:reflection.org /internal- /dep:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll","C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll" "PATH\DesktopTestsLauncher\bin\Debug\DesktopTestsLauncher.exe" "PATH\HSNDemo\bin\Release\HSNDemo.exe" "PATH\HSN_Coordinator Bluetooth IMAGE\BTWrapper\bin\Release\BTWrapper.dll" "PATH\HSN_Coordinator Bluetooth IMAGE\HSN_Coordinator\bin\Release\HSN_Coordinator.dll" "PATH\PortableStationLibrary\bin\PDA\PortableStationLibrary.dll" "PATH\PortableStationTests\bin\Debug\PortableStationTests.exe" "PATH\PortableStation\bin\Debug\PortableStation.exe"

MrefBuilder (v2.6.10621.1)
Copyright ¸ Microsoft 2006
Error: A file access error occured while attempting to load the addin assembly 'PATH\Documentation\Help\Presentation\Style\Configuration\MRefBuilder.exe'. The error message is: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'file:///PATH\Documentation\Help\Presentation\Style\Configuration\MRefBuilder.exe' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
Non-zero exit code: 1

Step 2 DaveSexton.DocProject.Engine.ExternalProcessException: Execute MRefBuilder:
The "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sandcastle\ProductionTools\MRefBuilder" process failed with exit code: 1.

Successful Steps: 1 of 12
Failed Steps: 1

Documentation help build failed.
```

If I use the DocProject External UI I get this message: "The imported project C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets was not found."

I have installed the .Net CF power toys, and I have that file in the 32bits version of the framework. How do I tell SandCastle to use the 32bits version???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tell to use the X86 Build platform. If it is auto, it will search in Framework64 directory. See if this blog post helps: http://www.simonrhart.com/2010/06/automating-your-windows-mobile-6x.html

It is related to TFS Build but the MSBUILD platform should be X86 and not Auto. Hope this helps you in finding a solution.